# page not rendering totaljs

Tags: node.js, total.js

I am new to Total JS and I am creating my first project. My sample page is not rendering and returning a 404.

[image]

Comment: That's weird, your code looks good to me. If you can share a link to your app source-code i can test it for you.

Comment: Thanks Molda. My bad. Folder name 'controller' is missing a 's'

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are starting like me, the above issue is due to the spelling mistake of the folder 'controller'. It should read 'controllers'.